# How to run websocket alongside laravel webpage in cPanel?

Tags: laravel, websocket

I have the Laravel project with websocket. I cloned the project on server with cPanel. Now I can access the running Laravel project through a sub domain like https://app.example.com. But I can not able to use the websocket with that domain name, because time out.

The websocket which I using is `wss`. I used the following command to run the websocket : `php artisan websocketsecure:init`. The command is running successfully, but I can't able to use. I tried the following address `wss://app.example.com:8090`

How can I access the secure websocket in the Laravel project?

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use React\EventLoop\Factory;
use React\Socket\SecureServer;
use React\Socket\Server;
use App\Http\Controllers\WebSocketController;

class WebSocketSecureServer extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'websocketsecure:init';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $loop   = Factory::create();
        $webSock = new SecureServer(
            new Server('0.0.0.0:8090', $loop),
            $loop,
            array(
                'local_cert'        => '/apache/conf/ssl.crt/server.crt', // path to your cert
                'local_pk'          => '/apache/conf/ssl.key/server.key', // path to your server private key
                'allow_self_signed' => TRUE, // Allow self signed certs (should be false in production)
                'verify_peer' => FALSE
            )
        );
        // Ratchet magic
        $webServer = new IoServer(
            new HttpServer(
                new WsServer(
                    new WebSocketController()
                )
            ),
            $webSock
        );
        $loop->run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have using any Content Distribution ? (i.e. Cloudflare)

Comment: Yeah! it is using cloudflare

Answer (score 1):

Well to run websockets you have 2 requirements basically:

- be able to run the service (check, you can do that apparently)
- Access the server (your server probably doesn't have port 8090 open to the outside world)

The last part is probably where your problem lies.

Comment: Thank you. But I already opened the port `8090` for in and out.

Comment: Any feedback , please

Comment: How about trying to debug the connections using some websocket plugin / tool first. Then you might be able to determine if the server or the client is the problem