# Host Laravel WebSocket Server on Cpanel

Tags: laravel, websocket, echo, cpanel, pusher

Does anyone have an idea of how to run Laravel serve on Cpanel?
laravel web socket work locally fine. [Link](https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/)

but how to run it on Cpanel ?

Comment: are you using shared server ?

Comment: no just normal cpanel

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57358652/how-to-run-websocket-alongside-laravel-webpage-in-cpanel

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution you can try if it works from the Laravel route
=>web.php

```
Route::get('run-surver', function(){ Artisan::call('websockets:serve'); });
```